# Google sheets query in need of a ifs statement

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to select different column depending on the column where a certain string is found.
This is my curent query.

> =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(Configuration!I5,"Employes!A2:Z"),"select Col26, Col3 where Col16 = '"&D27&"' or Col18 = '"&D27&"' or Col20 = '"&D27&"'")

Right now, it brings only 2 columns of data, but I would need it to also bring the columns following the one where it will find the sting "D27".

Comment: Can you share a spreadsheet with a minimal reproducible example

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Hi Mathieu, I have posted an answer yesterday. Let me know if it is ok for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=query({
QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(Configuration!I5,"Employes!A2:Z"),"select Col26,Col3,Col16,Col17");
QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(Configuration!I5,"Employes!A2:Z"),"select Col26,Col3,Col18,Col19");
QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(Configuration!I5,"Employes!A2:Z"),"select Col26,Col3,Col20,Col21")},
"select Col1,Col2,Col4 where Col3='"&D27&"'")
```